# How to create a cryptographically secure authentication without requiring keyboard input?

Tags: security, authentication, cryptography

I'm working on a system that will require a user to log in on a device using an account that they created on a website. Authentication will be over HTTPS, so that is not an issue. The application running on the device will allow in-app purchase using a credit card linked to their account, so it's important that the login credentials are secure enough that it would be difficult to attack using brute-force. The only problem is that the device that the user will be using will have limited user input capabilities (essentially, arrow keys and a selection button).

In this case, a typical username/password may be too cumbersome to enter, also requiring the development of a on-screen keyboard that is navigable via the arrow keys. Users would likely end up creating simple passwords that are easily cracked. However, once logged in, the user will be using an access token behind the scenes so they may not need to enter their password very many times.

The first step is that the user will need to enter their username or ID number. Using a number may be easier to enter, but also easier to guess. I'm open to suggestions in this area as well.

Next is the process of entering a "password". So here are a few ideas that I have, but I'm not a cryptography expert so I don't know how to gauge the level of security.

- User must first register the device. This might be a step that I require anyway, for extra security. The device would generate a key that is sent to the server and stored with the account. The key would be required when performing future authentication requests. The user would need to log into the website to approve the device. The device isn't going to have any sort of identifier, so unless you log in soon you wouldn't know if it was your device or someone else trying to spoof you. It would be nice to be able to create some sort of additional identifier, maybe a short code, phrase, or an image is displayed so you can know it's the same device that you just tried to register.
- Since entering a text password may be too difficult, as long as the device is registered, maybe a 4 digit passcode can be used when confirming in-app purchases. This may be nice anyway to prevent other users of the device from using your account without your permission. However, if they are watching you enter your passcode, then it's not really good for that purpose anymore.
- If registering the device is not necessary, instead of logging in with a text password, maybe the user is presented with images or phrases as options and they must choose the right combination of images/phrases that matches their account.

That's all I've got so far. What are your thoughts? How can I create an easy, but secure, login when in-app purchases are involved?

Comment: I like the way I make purchases in Steam and Xbox Live. In both cases I don't have to use a keyboard. I would check those out if I were you. ATM's are also a thing to check, they are more limited than your device. Also authenticating a user by letting him choose pictures is a sure way to let hackers steal your users' accounts. I don't need to do anything but look over someone's shoulder to discover their pictographic password, and being pictures I could do that from farther away than I'd need to with simple characters.

Comment: @Renan Thanks, I'm not familiar with Steam or Xbox Live authentication flow. Could you describe the process?

Comment: This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network: security.stackexchange.com
Please please please make entering another stackexchange site an option in "This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network". This is driving me nuts.

Comment: @owlstead In comments [no one can hear you scream](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @DuncanJones Just venting. These kind of higher level schemes/protocols are considered off topic on crypto...

Comment: This question asks about general security (and/or user interface design) practices rather than about a specific programming problem, and is therefore off-topic for Stack Overflow. You should ask it at the [IT Security Stack Exchange](http://security.stackexchange.com) (or possibly [User Experience Stack Exchange](http://ux.stackexchange.com)) instead.

Comment: Feel free to migrate this question to the appropriate site.

Answer (score 1):

I have been dealing with limited user input capability scenario. Would you describe the platform your app running on?It helps to fit the solution according to the platform security model.

Update: I hope you are not considering multi-user per device scenario. So, I am assuming that there is one user per device. The second assumption is the device may have a unique serial number that can be accessible through some APIs and the serial number is registered on the server in advance. 
At the initial stage, the user generates a random key through the device select button and the app confirms the success of key generation probably it display the serial number (the user may need to register the serial number for latter configuration). Behind the scenes, the app sends the new key with its serial number to the server. The server updates its serial number with the random key in the database entry. The device can block further key generation or may allow until it is finally configured with a dedicated user. The device also persist the serial number with the random key in the local database/file.  The user is then login to their account through a web interface to configure the device. For logged in user, the server presents a list of available devices and the user can choose a specific one that belongs to her/him and set four digit pin code. The server performs the following:

1. Link the user account, the serial number, the random key (the one the device sent at the beginning).
2. generate a token
3. generate a key using pin code  and the random key as a salt through Password based key derivative algorithm (PBKDF2)
4. encrypt the token using the key derived at step 3
5. Update database user row with the cipher token.

The user can sync the cipher token through the device select button. To unlock the app, user must enter the pin code through a simple numeric screen. The app uses the pin code and a random key (persisted at the beginning) and generates a PBKDF2 key and decrypt the token. PBKDF2 helps us to slow down the brute force a bit but it is possible to enforce time based or attempt based lockout as well. For instance after some trail, the app can drop the user credentials and force the user to configure from the scratch.

Comment: This will be an embedded device with custom input hardware. It will run on linux and the app will be written in Ruby.

Comment: In regards to your comment about multi-user, the plan is that there will be a primary user who is usually always logged in. The primary user can make in-app purchases, however, eventually I would like to allow guest users to log in, but will not have access to in-app purchase. Not sure how I'm going to deal with guest user authentication. Maybe 2-factor auth by creating temporary (revokable) token, and send email/text message for approval so that passcode is not displayed to others in plain text.